# Flutter: Show IOS Keyboard with external keyboard

Tags: ios, flutter, user-interface, bluetooth, keyboard

I have an external Bluetooth barcode reader connected to my phone.
Now when I click on a text box, the virtual keyboard no longer appears, but since my barcode reader can only enter things that I scan, I still need the virtual keyboard.

I can use the instructions that came with the barcode scanner to reopen the keyboard via a barcode, but that's not the solution because it would be too cumbersome.

How can I force the virtual keyboard to open?

Comment: Toggle keyboard visibility shortcut is `Command + Shift + K`

Comment: Did you read the question?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I thought this situation was happening in a virtual emulator.